# Best Practices on naming Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

I have for example a table name of Cars_Import

I need a view that will be called that grabs the data to be imported and that view is run and does the work to import the data into the Cars_Import table.

My problem is, I can't name the view the same, I have to differentiate it because I guess SQL server look at same name objects as a conflict no matter what type of object it is.

So for best practices in naming conventions that are generally accepted, when you have 2 objects that really relate to each other, and I know it's not good practice to append stuff like tbl, vw for view, etc. in the name, what would you suggest here as the view name related to Cars_Import?

I wouldn't want the view to have it for example switched around which would work but just seems messy to me such as Import_Cars

So what's the advice here on naming the table and its related view which will grab all data from that table that we need?  There is no business logic, it's just grabbing the data and we're gonna import it into a data warehouse, all the data as is initially.

Comment: I've never heard anyone object to hungarian (vw prefixes etc) notation in sql-server, particularly for objects like views. If you can't name the view after what it is (if for example it is a view over two tables name it for the tables) then I'd just use the prefix.

Comment: Can you add a term indicating why the view exists, e.g. `Cars_Import_InProcess` or `Cars_Import_Transfer`?

Answer (score 3):

Views are actually the one place where I don't mind a prefix or suffix that describes what it is. Unlike when comparing a table or a stored procedure, which are quite obvious because they are used differently, tables and views are largely interchangeable. So I find that this differentiation can be helpful when reverse engineering or troubleshooting code (and I'm talking about when you come across the name in a piece of code, not browsing the objects through Object Explorer, which makes things much more obvious by definition).

Your naming scheme is up to you, and you're largely not going to get a "correct" answer here, other than that you should apply your convention consistently and unilaterally, and do what you can to make sure your entire time buys into it and follows it as well. But I will say that I wouldn't balk at something like this:

```
Table: dbo.Cars_Import
View:  dbo.View_Cars_Import
```

But to me, this seems to imply that the view may just be something that sits over the table (say prettifying output, adding or hiding columns, etc.), not something that feeds the table. So I kind of agree with @HABO that maybe there is a better way to name this view that describes what it does.

Comment: yea that's what I kinda figured....you gotta use something to distinguish views...unless someone has a better way to do the naming on views, seems like this is the only way.

Comment: I guess I could do Import_All_Cars which would make a hell of a lot more sense than just Cars_Import or Import_Cars for the view name.  I come from an OOP background and the right thing to do is name methods what they do so it is self reading.  I'd apply the same to the DB